# Inserting MathJax into ContentEditable div

Tags: contenteditable, mathjax

I am trying to insert some MathJax code into a contentEditable div, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
  <script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML">      </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="editor" contentEditable="true" style="width:400px;height:400px;">
 </div>
```

and the JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#editor').focus();

  var code = "\\alpha";

  var html = '<span id="_math"><script type="math/tex;mode=in-line">'+ code +'</script></span>';

  document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, html);

  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, '_math']);

});
```

Which renders OK, but once this is inserted, the element freezes and further input is not possible. Can someone point out the problem here.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call MathJax when the content changes. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfq8po3a/ (note, I had to escape the `<` and `>` in html).

This was achieved with a few things:

1) move the MathJax logic into its own function, `refreshMathJax` which will re-populate the  tag and code.

2) call this function when first loading the page, and again onBlur.

3) Clear the editable element onFocus. Without this, the editable element can't be reused easily. You can change the onFocus callback function to instead replace the contentEditable html with the original LaTeX content.

Comment: I just realized this was a pretty old question; I hope someone still finds my answer useful!

Comment: I'd love to learn how to do this.  Your jsfiddle didn't work for me, though.  And I'd way to put the original latex back so that it could be edited in its native form.  Any suggestions?